# Books on the history of influential Treatises on Calculus and Analysis

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

I'm interested in the history of calculus & analysis and  looking for books that examine in some detail the history of writings on these subjects, mainly the history of the 17th-century "Treatise of Fluxions" to the 19th-c. "Cours d' Analyse".
Which works were significant and why? Which works, now forgotten, can still be useful in the understanding of the revolutionary rise of infinitesimal analysis? 
 Personal favorites would be welcome too. Any suggestions?

Comment: Start from books on [history of the *calculus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_calculus#Further_reading) : [Kline, Boyer, Edward](https://www.google.it/search?q=history+of+the+calculus&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTn8S8jcTdAhWKzoUKHUxOBXoQ_AUIECgB&biw=1366&bih=631)

Comment: Then move to modern editions of textbooks : [l'Hopital](https://books.google.it/books?id=cLE0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PR3), [Cauchy](https://books.google.it/books?id=M0or-HGe7D0C&pg=PR1).

Comment: _Mawhin, Jean_, [**The *Cours d’analyse infinitésimale* of Charles-Jean de La Vallée Poussin: from innovation to tradition**](https://www.mathematik.de/jahresberichte-archiv), Jahresber. Dtsch. Math.-Ver. 116, No. 4, 243-259 (2014). [ZBL1316.01010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1316.01010).

Comment: If you can read german I recommend [Spalt, Die Analysis im Wandel und im Widerstreit](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Die_Analysis_im_Wandel_und_im_Widerstrei.html?id=0fzWrQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: [Boyer's History of the Calculus and Its Conceptual Development](https://archive.org/details/TheHistoryOfTheCalculusAndItsConceptualDevelopment) (freely available) is a standard reference for this.

Comment: For complex analysis, see Chapter 10 “The Textbook Tradition” in Bottazzini and Gray ([2013](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3099398), pp. 691–759).